# Downloading files from linux server: wget scheme missing

Tags: linux, command-line, file-download

I am attempting to download a file from a red hat linux server:

```
wget /u01/d/ss/file.jpg
```

Yields:

```
/u01/d/ss/file/jpg: Scheme missing.
```

Comment: Since the posted answer isn’t really clear, I’ll say this: `wget` is a tool for downloading files from servers. You seem to understand that; you say “I am attempting to download a file from a Red Hat Linux server”.  And yet you’re running `wget` with a filename! How do you expect `wget` to know or figure out what server it needs to talk to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wget` only with `http:// ftp://` or `https://` and `ftps://` URL (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#URL-Format). If you want copy file use `cp` command.

Comment: It is my understanding that I would need to use SCP to download the file over SSH. My user account does not have a password, I log in with a network key. Is there any way to let SCP use this?

Comment: Hi @ColinG i don't have idea. You can try download file via `sftp` (see: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp ), maybe `mc` would help to connect without password.

I understand, path `/u01/d/ss/file.jpg` is a network drive?